# Как получить свойство объекта по цепочке из массива?

Tags: javascript

Мне нужно реализовать функцию которая принимает на вход 2 аргумента (объект, массив)

В массиве содержится цепочка свойств по которой функция должна вернуть значение. (Пример в коде)
Как можно реализовать эту функцию, если это реализуется рекурсией то мне нужно чтобы все переменные были внутри функции. Я делал это через рекурсию, но так чтоб переменные внутри были у меня не получается. Может как то можно без рекурсии это сделать?

```js
// Например есть такой объект:
const object = {
  name: 'danila',
  father: {
    miniFather: {
      name: 'petrovich',
      arr: [1, 2, 3],
    },
    name: 'bob',
    fn: function() {}
  },
  mother: {
    name: 'mariya',
  },
  grandmother: {
    grandson: {
      name: 'denis',
      age: 80,
    },
    name: 'marivanna',
  },

}

/*При вызове нужной функции с аргументами например:

  functionName(object, [father, miniFather, 'name']) выведет
  "petrovich"
 
   если например вызвать с массивом ['father', 'name'] 
   выведет 'bob'

   если просто ['name'] то вернет 'danila'

   если свойство по указанному пути не найдено вернет undefined
*/

//Я написал такую рекурсивную функцию, она работает как нужно,
//но проблема в том что все переменные должны быть внутри неё, 
// а у меня не получается это сделать

let x;
let idx = 0


function optionalChaining(obj, chain) {
  let last = chain.length - 1;
  for (let key in obj) {
    if (chain.length === 1) {
      if(obj.hasOwnProperty(chain[0])){
        return x = obj[chain[0]]
        
      }
  }
  
    if (obj[key] === obj[chain[idx]]) {
      idx += 1;
      if (obj[key].hasOwnProperty(chain[last])){
        x = obj[key][chain[last]]
        
      } 
    
    } 
    if (typeof obj[key] === 'object') {
      optionalChaining(obj[key], chain);
    } 
    
  } 
  return x;
} 

console.log(optionalChaining(object, ['father', 'name']));
```

Comment: что именно не получается?
не очень понятно как должна выглядеть функция?

Comment: @DonatMelnik Функция не должна трогать внешние переменные, а у меня idx и x за пределами функции. У меня не получается засунуть их внутрь чтобы всё работало. Она может выглядеть как угодно но с условием что все переменные с которыми она работает внутри неё.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я не понимаю, для чего нужны внешние `idx` и `x`.
Решение без рекурсии возможно, поскольку нам не требуется обход всех элементов, нас интересует только одна ветка.
Идея состоит в том, что мы двигаемся по свойствам объекта вглубь, в каждой итерации ссылаясь на дочерний элемент.
Код очень простой:

```js
const object = {
  name: 'danila',
  father: {
    miniFather: {
      name: 'petrovich',
      arr: [1, 2, 3],
    },
    name: 'bob',
    fn: function() {}
  },
  mother: {
    name: 'mariya',
  },
  grandmother: {
    grandson: {
      name: 'denis',
      age: 80,
    },
    name: 'marivanna',
  },

}

function path(obj, path) {
  for (let i = 0; i < path.length; i++) {
    if (obj.hasOwnProperty(path[i])) obj = obj[path[i]];
    else return null;
  }

  return obj;
}

console.log(
  path(object, ['father', 'name']),
  path(object, ['grandmother', 'grandson', 'age']),
  path(object, ['mother', 'wrongProperty']),
);

// Вывод: bob 80 null
```

Comment: Блин офигеть, спасибо)) Просто я настолько зациклился на рекурсии что в своих размышлениях очень сильно запутался. Я поражён что всё так просто оказалось) Спасибо!